# python poetry debug on vscode throws error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'how_long'"

Tags: python-poetry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uw1d2.png)

I am trying to run debug on vscode for poetry project and see this error. how to run debug on vscode to over come this error? code runs fine if not run with debug.

`from how_long import **version**
from how_long import timer

def test_version():
assert **version** == "0.1.2"

def test_wrap():

> ```
> @timer
> ```

def wrapped_function():
return

assert wrapped_function.**name** == "wrapped_function"
`

I created file with below content under vscode/launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "HOW-LONG-MASTER",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "${/Users/user1/python-practice/}",
            "module": "how_long",
            "args": []
        }
    ] }
```

I am getting below error:

```
The terminal process failed to launch: Starting directory (cwd) "${/Users/user1/python-practice/}" does not exist.
```